# Origins of the unified German declensions chart?

Tags: history, declension

In this [website](https://germanwithlaura.com/declension/#declensions:-the-smarter-way) , a chart is provided which when combined with the rules to it, one can derive all the other standard declension chart. Here is a picture of the same:

[image]

However, the only other place I've seen this covered is the author's YouTube channel. Is this an original information or does this 'unified chart' have some history behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it doesn't make a difference since the chart is wrong. It lists the strong ending for the Genitive case in masculine and neuter as *-s* when it's really *-n*. You can get the endings from the Wiktionary entry for any German adjective. For example [*gut*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gut#Declension) (Expand the "Positive forms of *gut*" tab.) Fortunately German adjectives are all regular with respect to declension, so once you've learned one adjective you've learned them all. (There are a couple of adjectives that have irregular comparatives.) The table you have is incomplete, at least for the traditional way of listing the declensions, because there is also a mixed declension. Perhaps the video explains how to get the mixed declension from the table, and I'm pretty sure it can be, but without this explanation there's information missing. Also, though this is a nitpick, native German speakers will have learned the order of the cases as NGDA, not NADG. NADG is (in my opinion) the most natural order for learners, but NGDA is the order they teach in schools in German speaking countries. I thought I'd mention it since if I didn't then someone else probably would.

There are many ways to cover German adjective inflection, and many authors of German grammars have their own method. The traditional way is to give a massive table with every combination of the four cases, the four gender/number classes (masc., fem., neut., pl.) and the three "strength" classes (strong, weak, mixed). That gives a table with at least 48 entries, more if you include predicate/adverb forms. I don't consider this a good way of teaching because it relies too much on table memorization; the 16 random-ish entries in the declension table for *der* is bad enough, 48 entries is asking too much. But you can reduce the memorization load by learning rules to determine the endings. [Nancy Thuleen's grammar site](http://nthuleen.com/teach/grammar/adjektivendungenexpl.html) has it all reduced to a relatively simple flow chart, which, unfortunately, has the same issue with the genitive case as the table you've given. But there are many different ways to formulate the rules to produce the same results. I think I've come up with three or four myself in my efforts to find patterns in the tables.

Comment: Thank you for the site, it seems more reliable than other sites I've encountered from top of the google searches. Sad that it is not as popular. Thanks for your continued assitance in my German learning.

Comment: @Buraian: You're welcome :) There are several sites with information on German grammar, and over time I've bookmarked enough of them that I usually find what I need without Google. In my experience the best are a bit hard to find.